# What are some ways to automatically test Swagger endpoints?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, swagger, integration-testing

Building a C# .NET Core API, I want to automatically test the endpoints in the documentation that is generated by Swagger as part of my build.

Are there some prebuilt packages or tools I can use to do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No more outdated API documentation.

This is the promise [Dredd](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd) makes. So should be able to help you with

> automatically test the endpoints in the documentation that is generated by Swagger as part of my build

I've used it in one project, it reads the description and step by step validates whether your API implementation replies with responses as they are described. There is a catch, though. It doesn't scale to live up to a real testing framework that can help you cover complex (chained) user journeys through your backend. It will introduce huge overhead, if you go down this path. But, in case you need simple docs validation - it works just fine. It can easily be your first line of defence, stage of the CICD pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Schemathesis](https://github.com/schemathesis/schemathesis), which utilizes property-based testing and generates and runs tests for Open API 2/3 schemas. It requires no configuration by default and works as a CLI tool. It also verifies all examples specified in the schema, which overlaps with some [Dredd](https://github.com/apiaryio/dredd) functionality - but you don't have to specify all examples; the tool will generate everything that is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Postman has beta API functions that will import an OAS document (with some limitations) and then generate a Collection from the spec. You can then add tests and run them fairly easily. https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/design_and_develop_apis/the_api_workflow/

What I think we need is extensions to OAS3 that specify test assertions. Then Postman or others could generate automated tests directly from the specification.